# Wordpress Plugin Development - Displaying custom pages for inventory

Tags: wordpress

Im looking for a bit of help with wordpress development.

I have created a simple plugin that enables people to manage categories for different cars, and then enter cars into each one of those categories.

What i need to be able to do, is display these cars on the frontend and have a car on each url without having to manually add pages for each car if that makes sense.

Is there anyone out there that could shoot me a link to a tutorial or help me out a bit.

Cheers

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs